# How to convert PowerPoint to PDF on the server

Tags: .net, powerpoint, converters

I am looking(hard) for a lightweight component that will convert PowerPoint files to PDF format. 
There is the SharePoint 2013 that can to this, but it is not suited for my needs as need something lightweight and not a SharePoint server farm.

Is there any components that I can use, preferably open like GhostScript?
It can be either .NET component or an EXE utility that will be executed from a command line.

Comment: @Blam At least one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Aspose.Slides library. I have used it many times with great success.

http://www.aspose.com/.net/powerpoint-component.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but it is too expensive for me.